# Login functionality from my platform INTO other sites?

Tags: api, curl, authentication, google-analytics

I am creating a software-platform in Symfony3 (a PHP framework). In this platform, there needs to be a page with links to approximately 20 different websites (among others: Google Analytics, Google TagManager, Rocket.Chat)

My goal is to enable the following functionality:
Upon having clicked on one of these links that are in my platform, I want to redirect the user to that particular site, while having them logged in.

**So for example:**
*There is a **'link'** to Google Analytics and when being clicked, the user needs to be redirected to their campaign within Google Analytics.*

Note: The username/password that will be used to perform this login will be the same throughout all the different sites. We have a database with these credentials for each user, which we want to use to login to those different services.

- I was thinking about using **cURL**, but this would not be a universal technique. (and bring forwards many security implications)
- Another option would be to use the **Google API** to perform an authentication, but I could not find such functionality. (Normally, it is the other way around: logging into your platform by means of a google account)

I look forward hearing from your input!

Kind regards,

Jeroen

Comment: Simplest way would probably be not to create your own login system but use one of the Big OAuth providers - e.g. with a Google Account you can login to all Google products and a host of other platforms, and it would be much more convenient for your users not to have to remember another set of credentials.

Comment: But aren't these OAuth providers used to get access for API calls only or to authenticate a user against the OAuth server of for example Google? What I need is the other way around. Authenticate and login to a Google Analytics account